# A hover-activated 3D Parallax effect on my website

Tags: html, 3d, background-image, parallax, mousehover

I want to create a hover-activated 3D Parallax Effect for my homepage.

I want to achive something like that:

https://www.hellomonday.com/

It has a 3D effect but also it is responsive to my mouse movement. What should I search? How can I create this effect?

Answer (score 2):

[Parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) by Matt Wagerfield (@mwagerfield) and Claudio Guglieri (@claudioguglieri)

It is a robust little parallax engine, giving you a quick, simple api to get going with all your parallax needs. Forget scrolling though, parallax.js utilizes your devices orientation and will fall back to cursor positions if no motion detection is available… this really gives you that sexy responsive feel.

May be this could help you to acheive what you are seeking for :)

Alternatively if you want to use Primitive JS Then you have to track the movement of mouse and trigger some event accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV"></div>

<p>Mouse over the rectangle above, and get the coordinates of your mouse pointer.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>


<script>
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    myFunction(event);
});

function myFunction(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coor;
    if( x == "54")
      alert("Cordinate triggered")
    }
</script>
```

As soon as you hit x coordinate as 54, alert box will appear